# How do I retrieve and display a different values depending on which form I submit?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<form action="apply.html" method="post">
      <div class="cloudinformation">
        <h2>
          Job reference number:
        </h2>
        <h4>
        1FN43
      </h4>
          <input type="submit" value="Apply">
      </div>
    </form>
    
    <form action="apply.html" method="post">
      <div class="consultantinformation">
        <h2>
          Job reference number:
        </h2>
        <h4>
        6LZ9W
      </h4>
          <input type="submit" value="Apply">
      </div>
    </form>
```

```html
     <form action="https://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php" method="post" id="regform">
     
        <label>Job Reference Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="onlyletters" name="onlyletters" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" minlength="5" maxlength="5" placeholder="Reference number for specified job.." required="required">
      </form>
```

How do I set it up so that, depending on which job press apply for, it will retrieve the job reference number of the specified job and display it in read-only format on the apply.html, which is the form you are redirected to when you press "apply"?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not clear . Elaborate some more. And what is 2nd snippet for

Comment: @Rana

Basically, the first HTML snippet that I sent contains 2 forms, both containing a unique job reference number (1FN43 and 6LZ9W). Both are linked to another form, which is shown in the second snippet. Using JavaScript, How would I make it so that, depending on which of the two forms are submitted, the job reference number for the submitted form will be shown in a read-only form on the form they are redirected to. If you still don't understand what I'm trying to do, please let me know. The second snippet has no other purpose than to display the job reference number

Answer (score 1):

Does this is what you want to achieve

```js
var applyBtn = document.querySelectorAll("button")
var hideFormAll = document.querySelectorAll(".cloudinformation")

for (let i = 0; i < applyBtn.length; i++) {
  applyBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var referNumb = applyBtn[i].parentElement.querySelector(".refree")
    document.querySelector("#onlyletters").value = referNumb.textContent
    document.querySelector(".formAll").style.display = "none"
    document.querySelector("#regform").style.display = "block"

  })
}
```

```css
#regform {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="formAll">
  <div class="cloudinformation">
    <h2>
      Job reference number:
    </h2>
    <h4 class="refree">1FN43</h4>
    <button>Apply</button>
  </div>



  <div class="consultantinformation">
    <h2>
      Job reference number:
    </h2>
    <h4 class="refree">6LZ9W</h4>
    <button>Apply</button>
  </div>
</div>


<form action="https://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php" method="post" id="regform">

  <label>Job Reference Number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="onlyletters" name="onlyletters" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" minlength="5" maxlength="5" placeholder="Reference number for specified job.." required="required" readonly>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't make it clear enough. I meant that the second snippet is a separate HTML and that the job reference number has to be stored using local session storage to transfer it between the HTML files. The first snippet with the two forms is a separate HTML file from the second snippet, which will display the number in read-only form.

Comment: @snailleaker than that is `backend` work like getting `data` from user and process it through the second one to display the desired `data`

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @snailleaker changed some of the code such that 2nd form is not visible and only visible when clicked on apply

Comment: Sorry but I think you maybe still don't understand. The 2nd form needs to be on a separate HTML file, not on the same one. Using local session storage in JavaScript, you're meant to retrieve it from the first snippet and display it in the first snippet and both snippets are in two different HTML files.